# Form Field Event on Update, INSERT INTO another table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

When "yes" is entered into a form field of my database I want to trigger the insertion of a new row of data in another table "in the background" and continue moving through my form.  Any thoughts?  Not sure of the "If" statement syntax...get debug error on "DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL"

```
Private Sub Data_Destruction_Certificate_AfterUpdate()

Dim strSQL As String, Response As Integer

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Data_Destruction ([DonateID], [Make-Model], [Model_Serial_Number], [Media_Type], [Media_Serial_Number], [Date of Destruction]) " & "VALUES ('" & DonateID & "', '" & "Unknown" & "', '" & "Make - Model" & "', '" & "Model_Serial_Number" & "', '" & "Media_Type" & "', '" & "Media_Serial_Number" & "', '" & 1 / 1 / 2000 & "')"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Response = acDataErrAdded      'now requeries the database to refresh the list
    Response = acDataErrContinue

End Sub
```

Did as instructed. can't post an image...don't have the points.  the initial "Run Time Error is 3346, "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

The debug print out stated:

```
INSERT INTO Data_Destruction ([DonateID], [Make-Model], [Model_Serial_Number], [Media_Type], [Media_Serial_Number], [Date of Destruction]) VALUES ('24', 'Unknown', 'Make - Model', 'Model_Serial_Number', 'Media_Type', 'Media_Serial_Number', '0.0005')
```

apparently my "date" value syntax is incorrect

OK...fixed the date with #....# and added in the MediaID (autonumber field)-- all the fields in the table I want to insert are now included.  Ran the code and got:

```
INSERT INTO Data_Destruction ([MediaID],[DonateID], [Make-Model], [Model_Serial_Number], [Media_Type], [Media_Serial_Number], [Date_of_Destruction]) VALUES ('', '28', 'Unknown', 'Make - Model', 'Model_Serial_Number', 'Media_Type', 'Media_Serial_Number', '1/1/2000')
```

Comment: Add `Debug.Print strSQL` on the next line after the one which begins with `strSQL =`.  Remove or disable `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`.  Run the code.  Go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there) and copy the `INSERT` statement text.  Paste that statement into your question.  Also include the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of your `INSERT` statement includes 8 `VALUES` but only 7 fields.  I formatted the statement to make it easier to count them:

```sql
INSERT INTO Data_Destruction
    (
        [MediaID],
        [DonateID],
        [Make-Model],
        [Model_Serial_Number],
        [Media_Type],
        [Media_Serial_Number],
        [Date_of_Destruction]
    )
VALUES
    (
        '',
        '28',
        'Unknown',
        'Make - Model',
        'Model_Serial_Number',
        'Media_Type',
        'Media_Serial_Number',
        '1/1/2000'
    )
```

You need to remove one of those `VALUES` or include an eighth field to accept the extra value.

I suggest you paste the `INSERT` statement into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer.  Adjust the statement there as needed until the errors go away and it adds a row to the table with the values you intend.  Once you have it working there, revise your VBA code to produce the same statement text.

Afterward I recommend you discard `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` and execute the statement like this ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

However, I'm unsure whether you will need anything more.  Mainly I'm confused because I don't understand why you have these ...

```vb
Response = acDataErrAdded
Response = acDataErrContinue
```

What did you intend *Response* to accomplish?